# Nested for loop only executing for last item of list

Tags: python, nested-loops

I am trying to read a list of directories from a text file, and use that to copy the directories to a new location. My code below seems to only complete the "#Perform copy or move files" loop for the last item of the list. Can someone please point me in the direction as to why?

```
import os
import shutil

operation = 'copy' # 'copy' or 'move'

text_file = open('C:\User\Desktop\CopyTrial.txt', "r")
lines = text_file.readlines()

for line in lines: 
    new_file_name = line[47:]
    root_src_dir = os.path.join('.',line)
    root_target_dir = os.path.join('.','C:\User\Desktop' + new_file_name)

    # Perform copy or move files. 
    for src_dir, dirs, files in os.walk(root_src_dir):
        dst_dir = src_dir.replace(root_src_dir, root_target_dir)

        if not os.path.exists(dst_dir):
            os.mkdir(dst_dir)

        for file_ in files:
            src_file = os.path.join(src_dir, file_)
            dst_file = os.path.join(dst_dir, file_)
            if os.path.exists(dst_file):
                os.remove(dst_file)
            if operation is 'copy':
                shutil.copy(src_file, dst_dir)
            elif operation is 'move':
                shutil.move(src_file, dst_dir)

text_file.close()
```

Comment: Do you mean the last `line` in `lines`?

Comment: Try printing `root_src_dir` and making sure it contains files to copy.

Comment: Why do this with Python when you can just do a recursive directory copy from the command prompt?

Comment: @Barmar yes that is correct, the code only works fully for the last `line` in `lines` . If i print  `root_src_dir` inside the first for loop it prints the directory for each line, but if i do it inside the second for loop it prints only the directory for the last `line` in `lines`

Comment: That means that `os.walk()` isn't finding anything to process.

Comment: Side note, don’t check equality of strings using `is`, use `==` instead. Please it’s not always reliable for bigger strings as they’re not always stored in the same memory location.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar and @abccd, I really appreciate your help. I have noticed that if i manually remove the last `line` of `lines` from the text file, then the code again works for the directory that is now the "new" last `line` of `lines`. This shows that it is able to find things to process for the other directories, but i still cant work out why it does not complete it for the other directories contained earlier in the text file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lines returned by `readlines()` include the trailing newlines, but you're not removing this when you create the filename from it. The reason it works for the last line is because your file doesn't end with a newline.

Use `rstrip()` to remove trailing whitespace.

```
for line in lines:
    line = line.rstrip()
    ...
```